# Does $.ready fire before or after all inline <script>'s have been loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

At the core, this is a javascript question but I'm interfacing the event with jQuery.

Here's an example case:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="waiting_on_ready.js" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="http://somewhere.com/not_cached.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Does the $.ready callback in waiting_on_ready.js have to wait for not_cached.js to be loaded? Does it wait for not_cached.js to be executed?

Comment: may be you can put an alert and try

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213281/does-javascript-have-to-be-in-the-head-tags

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes and yes.

The execution of `<script>` elements is synchronous *except* when using the HTML5 ["async" attribute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28HTML5%29#Attributes). The synchronous execution of JavaScript is required (unless otherwise requested not to be) because the JavaScript can modify the document stream through `document.write`, etc. (However, the actual fetching of resources may be in parallel.)

Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks! Is there an event that fires before external scripts are loaded, but after the DOM is ready to manipulate? Or is the DOM not ready, by definition, until <scripts> are loaded and/or executed?

Comment: @Aaron It isn't ready until it's ready :) The execution of the script elements prevents the DOM from being ready (e.g. "prevents </body> from being read", because stream can be modified) until they are done running. Remember, the first script element is run before all subsequent script elements and this can be used. Note that "done running" just means that the code is executed -- if those script have setup timers and/or other events then those timers may trigger after the DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 7):

Ready fires when all DOM elements are ready for manipulation.

When the browser comes across a script element, DOM parsing stops until the script has been executed, so because of how it all works, it fires after all scripts are loaded.

Comment: I had to give it to pst since he was first with the correct response. Thanks though! Have an upvote :)

Comment: My answer was wrong at first, so I'll live with it. An upvote is better then nothing. :)

Answer (score 1):

`$(document).ready()` would not be triggered prior to `not_cached.js` to be loaded and executed (assuming execution in `not_chached.js` is synchronous)

Answer (score 0):

the `$.ready` script executes after the page is fully loaded, `as the onload event does`, however if an inline script is found  then it is executed.