# Is $(document).ready() called after loading all script files in the body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, document-ready, ready

Is $(document).ready() called after loading script js files in the body ?

If I put $(document).ready() in the head in script element which take a callback function that using a functions declared in a file which its script element loaded in the body like that :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
hello();
})
</script>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<script src="http://somewhere/helloFuncDeclaration.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Is it a right way to do that and guarantee that the helloFuncDeclaration.js will be loaded before calling the function hello() ?

Comment: `$({
hello();
})` is syntax error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be sure, use window onload handler:

```
$(window).on('load', hello);
```

Or use it like this:

```
<script onload="hello()" src="http://somewhere/helloFuncDeclaration.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: But it is called after loading all images too, Do you think it is a good idea to use load !!!

Comment: The good idea would be to call hello() function inside helloFuncDeclaration.js file after declaration or use the onload event of this script tag

Comment: helloFuncDeclaration.js maybe some remote library and I want to calling the function or declaring some objects in my own code block...

Comment: I have used $(document).ready() for my own custom jquery code. And for all advertisement scripts (like Google AdSense or other providers) I activated them using $(window).load(), which works well!

Answer (score 2):

To be sure , you can use window.load

```
$(window).load(function(){
   hello();
})
```

> The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have
>   been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element
>   associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the
>   window object.

- http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Answer (score 1):

`$(document).ready()` runs after all assets were loaded, so - yes

Comment: it runs after DOM is ready, so no

Comment: I don't understand why this answer was down voted. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397534/how-soon-will-jquerydocument-ready-be-called and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195257/does-ready-fire-before-or-after-all-inline-scripts-have-been-loaded clearly state that `script` inside the body will always be loaded before the ready event fires.

Comment: No, it's called after DOM elements are downloaded not all assets.

Comment: That means scripts inside the body tag. Optimally you do not have scripts inside the body tag.

Comment: this answer is wrong and it could lead to bugs in JS. document.ready event do not means, that all JS from body was loaded.