# JQuery: $(document).ready work only when embedded in HTML file?

Tags: jquery

What is the consensus rule for **placing** JQuery scripts used for things like navigation menus? Is it best to embed the script in the HTML file itself or link to it in the head? Because can the $(document).ready function truly work if the script is not embedded in the HTML file?

Comment: I link to all of the scripts at bottom of the body instead of the Head.  I don't remember where I got that from, but it works.

Comment: You shoud search, this is duplicate

Comment: If you put it at the bottom of the body, document.ready is unnecessary.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213281/does-javascript-have-to-be-in-the-head-tags , as it's answered there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's "BEST" to link it at the bottom of your file, just before the close-body tag. The reason for that is that typically most if not all of your markup and content will exist on the page before the script even starts running. There are occasionally exceptions when you need a script earlier, in which case you can link it in the head... but these are usually pretty rare.

Additionally, you should actually link your jQuery using Google (or jQuery.com) CDN links with a local fallback. This is what I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined'){document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));}
</script>
```

As far as the document.ready function, it SHOULD be included in an external script file (rare cases where you'd put it elsewhere) which SHOULD be included near the end of your document, AFTER the jQuery library has been called.

That's the long answer.

The short answer is, yes. A doc.ready function can "truly work" fine even if its not placed directly in your html file.

EDIT:
Couple additional points, while I'm thinking about it (that you may or may not care about).

- You CAN have multiple doc.ready functions. They will stack in the order that the browser encounters them, and run when the page has finished loading.
- Doc.ready runs once any code-based content has finished loading (html,css,js). If you need a script to run only after all your images and other media content has also finished loading you can use `$(window).load(function(){ ..stuff.. });`

Comment: So would best practice be to LINK to an EXTERNAL script at the end of the file (after the libraries have been called) or EMBED a script in the HTML at the end of the document (also after the libraries have been called)?

Comment: You're contradicting yourself: if jquery is included before `</body>`, document.ready is completely unnecessary, because the whole DOM will be already loaded.

Comment: it's not that it can or cannot truly work, there are specific rules that make it work or not. document.ready() obviously fires only once: when the browser has loaded the header resources and has constructed the document body markup. So any doc.ready() in external scripts, and anywhere, will properly work, if the listener is added before the document is ready.

Comment: @oceanic815 It doesn't matter if you link or embed, but if you link the HTML will definitely look better/cleaner. Also, I don't know which libraries you're talking about, but libraries/plugins that depend on jquery must be included *after* jquery itself.

Comment: @Oceanic815 I'd recommend you to read https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/include-scripts-properly , it has a lot of useful recommendations about this very subject.

Comment: @bfavaretto When I said library I meant the JQuery itself (jquery.1.9.1.min.js). That should be called after the body tag but before my own external JQuery scripts, correct?

Comment: @oceanic815 add jquery, then your scripts, then `</body>`. Then you don't even need document.ready

Comment: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom this one specifically adresses your question....

Comment: @bfavaretto I'm not contradicting myself because the point about including scripts at the end of your file, and whether or not a doc.ready will work inside or outside of your html were two completely separate points. Best practice is to include scripts at the end. Doc.ready may be moot at that point, but it's still best to include scripts that should only run when the doc is ready.. inside a doc.ready function.